# Как правильно достать коллекцию сущностей в entity framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Хочу достать из таблицы (OrganizationGroups) многим ко многим данные, но выбивает ошибку типа - `"Invalid column name 'OrganizationGroupId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'OrganizationGroupId'."`

Примеры запроса

```
 IList<Group> groups = await _repository
                    .OrganizationGroupRepository.FindByCondition(e => e.OrganizationId == organizationId)
                    .Include(e => e.Groups)
                    .Select(e => e.Group)
                    .ToListAsync();

                IList<OrganizationGroup> organizationGroups = await _repository
                    .OrganizationGroupRepository.FindByCondition(e => e.OrganizationId == organizationId)
                    .Include(e => e.Groups)
                    //.Select(e=>e.Group)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

BaseEntity:

```
 public class BaseEntity: IBaseEntity
    {
        [Column("id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Column("CreatedBy")]
        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Column("ModifiedBy")]
        public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Column("CreatedOn")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Column("ModifiedOn")]
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    }
```

Organization:

```
   [Table("Organizations")]
    public class Organization: BaseEntity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("OrganizationCode")]
        private int _organizationCode { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int OrganizationCode => _organizationCode;

        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Group:

```
 [Table("Groups")]
    public class Group:BaseEntity
    {
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
OrganizationGroups:

```
   [Table("OrganizationGroups")]
    public class OrganizationGroup: BaseEntity
    {

        [Column("GroupId")]
        public Guid GroupId { get; set; }

        public Group Group { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

        [Column("OrganizationId")]
        public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }

        public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }
```

Таблица в БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

OrganizationGroupRepository:

```
 public class OrganizationGroupRepository : BaseRepository<OrganizationGroup, ProjectXContext>
    {
        public OrganizationGroupRepository(ProjectXContext context) : base(context) { }
    }
```

Context:

```
 public class ProjectXContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid>
        {
            public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
            public DbSet<CourseCategory> CourseCategories { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
            public DbSet<CustomerGroup> CustomerGroups { get; set; }
            public DbSet<CustomerCourse> CustomerCourses { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
            public DbSet<FileStorage> FileStorages { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
            public DbSet<OrganizationGroup> OrganizationGroups { get; set; }
            public DbSet<OrganizationCategory> OrganizationCategories { get; set; }
            public DbSet<OrganizationCustomer> OrganizationCustomers { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Storage> Storages { get; set; }
            public DbSet<StorageType> StorageTypes { get; set; }
            public DbSet<UserRefreshToken> UserRefreshTokens { get; set; }
            public DbSet<YouTubeStorage> YouTubeStorages { get; set; }
    
            public ProjectXContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectXContext> options)
            : base(options)
            {
               //  Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                
                base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    
    
    
                builder.Entity<User>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "sys_Users"); });
                builder.Entity<Role>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "sys_Roles"); });
                builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("sys_UserRoles"); });
                builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("sys_UserClaims"); });
                builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("sys_UserLogins"); });
                builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("sys_UserTokens"); });
                builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("sys_RoleClaims"); });
            }
        }
```

BaseRepository:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity where TDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected readonly TDbContext _context;

    public DbSet<TEntity> Entities => _context.Set<TEntity>();
    public DatabaseFacade Database => _context.Database;

    protected BaseRepository(TDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(new TimeSpan(0,5,0)); // 5 min
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddRangeAsync(entities);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task<bool> ContainsAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ContainsAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        return  _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Guid id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
         _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task RemoveRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
              //  _context.Dispose();
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~BaseRepository()
    // {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
       //  GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

При запросе должен получить одну организацию и коллекцию групп.

В чем ошибка или что нужно сделать, чтобы запрос сработал?

Comment: `Invalid column name 'OrganizationGroupId` видимо вы запрашиваете колонку, которой нет в бд

Comment: @tym32167 , как видите по свойствам, то нет, это генерирует сам фреймворк, я не пойму, как правильно описать и/или запросить

Comment: В связи многие-ко-многим участвуют 3 таблицы, а значит и 3 класса (если у вас ef core), Вы показываете 1 таблицу и 1 класс, то есть вы показываете не все, что у вас есть.

Comment: @tym32167 , добавил.

Comment: Я не вижу у вас связи многие-ко-многим. Что такое `BaseEntity`? Где ещё 2 таблицы?

Comment: что такое `OrganizationGroupRepository`? Как вы работаете с контекстом?

Comment: @ tym32167 , добавил, если что-то еще нужно, сообщите.

Comment: Кажется я начинаю понимать. У вас связь есть один-ко-многим, между `Group` и  `OrganizationGroup`, чтобы такая связь действительно была, вам надо иметь поле `OrganizationGroupId` в таблице `Group`. А у вас этого поля там нет.

Comment: @tym32167 , спасибо, решение опубликовал.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение и правильную логику.

Класс многие ко кногим:

```
 [Table("OrganizationGroups")]
    public class OrganizationGroup: BaseEntity
    {
        [Column("GroupId")]
        public Guid GroupId { get; set; }

        public Group Group { get; set; }

        [Column("OrganizationId")]
        public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }

        public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }
```

Организация:

```
   [Table("Organizations")]
    public class Organization: BaseEntity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("OrganizationCode")]
        private int _organizationCode { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int OrganizationCode => _organizationCode;

        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<OrganizationGroup> OrganizationGroups { get; set; }
    }
```

Группа:

```
  [Table("Groups")]
    public class Group:BaseEntity
    {
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<OrganizationGroup> OrganizationGroups { get; set; }
    }
```

Запрос:

```
Organization organization = await _repository
                    .OrganizationRepository.FindByCondition(e=>e.Id == organizationId)
                    .Include(e => e.OrganizationGroups).ThenInclude(e=>e.Group)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```